# Conditional not reading data correctly

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, console.log

I have a simple if-else statement. When I console.log the value of `result`, I get a `null`. As you can see below, I handle the `null` response with an alert. My issue is that the conditional is not reading the `result` value correctly. It is firing the else statement causing the "Success" alert to go off. Why would this be happening? Is it possible the event is throwing it off?

```
     function(result, event) {
         console.dir('result: ' + result);
         console.dir('event: ' + event);
         if(result == null){
            alert('FAILED- Please contact your administrator, an error has occurred');
              $('#processing').modal('hide');
         }
         else{
            alert('Success- Your Bank Data Has Been Refreshed');
              $('#processing').modal('hide');
         }
         return parentIdparam;
     },
```

[image]

UPDATE:
Discovered that the conditional works for this endpoint:
`req.setEndpoint('https://dev.test.com/bl/api/v2/GetBank?sfBankDataId=a34S00111111glIIAS&sfRecordIdToAttachBankStatement=a34S000545454lIIAS');`

but not for this one:
  `req.setEndpoint('https://dev.test.com/bl/api/v2/GetBank?sfBankDataId=' + bankDataId + '&sfRecordIdToAttachBankStatement=' + accountId);`

bankDataId and accountId both have values. I get a `null` result for both endpoints. But one works with the conditional and one doesn't.

Comment: Try result === null once

Comment: `"null" != null` =)

Comment: some sort of type coercion is going on, try using ===

Comment: note `console.log()` displays the CURRENT state of the variable (current relative to you viewing, not runtime), so it can be deceptive at times... a good way to make sure it's actually null is to log with `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));`

Comment: Another note `==` is not the same as `===` when checking for "null": `undefined == null` evaluates to true, `undefined === null` evaluates to false

Comment: I dug a little deeper and found that it has something to do with my webservice endpoint and what it's returning. When I hardcode my endpoint vs when I use a variable for my endpoint, I get the same null value for the `result`. BUT when I hardcode the endpoint it must be returning something that I am unable to see because the if statement works. I will update my question with these findings.

Comment: also, it might be more useful for you to check the result using if (!result)

Comment: I'll bet it's returning the string `'null'` rather than a null value. What does `console.log(typeof result)` show?

Comment: @Barmar possibly, let me try adding a few more filters to the condition...

Comment: @Barmar that worked! Crazy I didn't look like a string at all. Thank you for helping :) If you want to post that as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Maybe it's returning JSON, and you forgot to use `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `result` contains a string, not an actual null value. So it should be:

```
if (result == 'null')
```

I suspect the API is returning JSON, so you should be using `JSON.parse(result)`.